# apt-get over proxy, error "405 Method Not Allowed"

Tags: apt, proxy, tor

I try to setup the **Advanced Packaging Tool** (apt-get) to work over TOR. The Web-Browser is working fine, YouTube-DL needs **--proxy "socks5://127.0.0.1:9050"**, wget douse not work

```
wget: unable to resolve host address
```

and some other Programs working fine over TOR

I already tryd this all:

---

**torrc**

```
SOCKSPort 127.0.0.1:9050
HTTPTunnelPort 127.0.0.1:3030
```

---

**/etc/environment**

```
http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3030"
```

---

**bash.bashrc**

```
export https_proxy=https://127.0.0.1:3030
```

---

**/etc/apt/apt.conf**

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3030";
```

---

[image: System-Proxy-Configuration]

---

[image: apt update]

---

[image: Editors]

---

Answer (score 1):

apt-get does not support socks proxies. You need to be sure if the tool you are using does have support to it. That is probably why you get those "405" messages.

**Method 1**

[Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/) is the guy you should check out to "convert" your socks5 connections into http proxy, so you will have a local http proxy without cache.

First, clear your `http_proxy` variable, but keep your `tor` service running and installed. After that, install privoxy:

```
sudo apt install privoxy
```

Edit `/etc/privoxy/config` and add the following line(no mistakes here, there is a dot at the end of the line)

```
forward-socks5 / localhost:9050 .
```

This way, all your requests to `privoxy` will be redirect to `tor`. Ascii art to help :)

```
+--------+http +---------+socks5 +------+
| apt|get+-----> privoxy +------>+ tor  +--------> INTERNET
+--------+     +---------+       +------+
```

Restart privoxy and export the `http_variable`

```
sudo systemctl restart privoxy
http_proxy="localhost:8118"
```

**Method 2**

Use [`torsocks`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/torsocks) to encapsulate all your requests through tor. On this second method, i'm still assuming you have `tor` already working and configured on it's default ports.

```
sudo apt install torsocks
```

Then

```
sudo torsocks apt update
```

Comment: If all the data go´s through a proxy, my online games will have a terrible ping.

Comment: nice... **torsocks** is working fine. **THX** -- **VLC** streaming over **TOR* is not working anymore, in Ubuntu 16.04 it works on the same settings as i have now in 18.04?

Comment: Well, about VLC, it seems that it never officially supported socks5 as you can see here - https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/20675?cversion=0&cnum_hist=6 - Try using `torsocks` too :)  . If you take a time to think, this "proxy" done by privoxy is only a "translator" from socks5 to http, and it listens to your localhost address. I can't imagine how it would interfere with your gaming if don't use it.

Comment: I already try´d **torsocks** with **vlc** by starting **vlc** in command line **torsocks vlc** but it douse not work. I trying to install **Privoxy** from source code but it douse not work. I followed the **INSTALL** instruction but the program won´t get installed.

Comment: It is at least compiling? ( `make`  works but `make install`  dont)

Comment: Exactly.  i started a new trade here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510791/privoxy-installation-of-source-code-will-not-work?noredirect=1#comment944283_510791

Comment: HTTPTunnelPort in tor is  not socks.

Comment: Privoxy from source code ERROR: **GNUmakefile:835: recipe for target 'install' failed** -- **make: *** [install] Error 1**

Comment: i tried **socks** and **http** always the sam.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo on your http(s) settings. It missing a //

It should be:

```
http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3030"
https_proxy="https://127.0.0.1:3030"
```

Comment: its just in this trade

Comment: I added the second line **https_proxy="https://127.0.0.1:3030"**. Still not working.