# Privoxy Installation of source code will not work

Tags: source, privoxy

I am trying to install [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/) from [source code (3.0.28 (stable))](https://www.privoxy.org/sf-download-mirror/Sources/), but it dose not work. I followed the INSTALL instruction, but the program won´t install.

---

```
GNUmakefile:835: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

---

```
It is strongly recommended to not run Privoxy as root.
You should configure/install/run Privoxy as an unprivileged user...
```

---

```
Then, to build from either unpacked tarball or CVS source:
```

---

```
apt build-dep privoxy
```

---

```
    autoheader
    autoconf
    ./configure      # (--help to see options)
    make             # (the make from GNU, sometimes called gmake)
    su               # Possibly required
    make -n install  # (to see where all the files will go)
    make -s install  # (to really install, -s to silence output)
```

---

Installed as USER
[image]

---

Installed as ROOT
[image]

Comment: Please convert text to text (see https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/4778 )

Comment: Please proof-read, and fix errors, so that we can answer).

Comment: This is the text of the install instruction file, how to install the program, not my text.

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. Those are two separate comments. I am NOT asking you to proof read the text from the computer, that should be verbatim, and pasted as text (not a picture). Your text should be proof-read, and errors corrected. And add some context: You start with an error message. How did you get there?

Comment: You need to scroll up. Im not starting with a error message. First of all, I describe what I did:    **I am trying to install Privoxy from source code (3.0.28 (stable)), but it dose not work. I followed the INSTALL instruction, but the program won´t install.**

Answer (score 0):

I just looked through you session text. You first tried to run `make -s install` as a normal user, but got permission errors. You then did it as root, and was told-off by the installer, for being root.

Security on Unix (including Gnu/Linux), is not binary (root/not-root): You can give access to directories to other users.

One way to do this is:

- create an admin group (`sudo addgroup admin && sudo adduser «your-user-name» admin` )
- change the group ownership of `/usr/local` (`sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local; sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local`).
- do the install as admin (`sudo --group admin make install`).

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Can't add user to group, error: **Command 'add' not found, did you mean:...**

Comment: Sorry I fixed the error: there is no space, just `addgroup`.

Comment: It worked now **chgrp -R admin /usr/local; chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local** executed without Error. Then i reinstalled Privoxy with the flowing commands in this order as SuperUser **make uninstall**, **make clean**. Then as User: **autoheader**, **autoconf**, **./configure, **sudo --group admin make install** and got the same error message: **GNUmakefile:835: recipe for target 'install' failed -- make: *** [install] Error 1**

Comment: I also have a warning on compiling (make): **jcc.c: In function 'main':
jcc.c:4016:7: warning: ignoring return value of 'chdir', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
       chdir("/");**